# How to find the length of a string in C++

Tags: c++

I a writing a program and I need to write a function that returns the amount of characters and spaced in a string. I have a string(mystring) that the user writes, I want the function to return the exact amount of letters and spaces in string, for examples "Hello World" should return 11, since there are 10 letters and 1 space. I know string::size exists but this returns the size in bytes, which is of no use to me.

Comment: Is this a cstring or a string class instance?

Comment: I am new to C++(actually started 2 days ago), I included <string> and used std::string mystring; ,I am not sure what a string class instance is, but I don't think its a cstring or I would #Include <cstring>?

Comment: FYI http://rextester.com/BYLO97697

Comment: Use `mystring.size()`

Comment: string::size returns the size in bytes,I need the amount of characters, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @ApprenticeCoder how are you inputting the string , is it by cin?

Comment: getline (cin,mystring)

Comment: If your question is  "How do I count the number of unicode codepoints in a UTF-8 encoded byte stream?", then you should probably ask that :-) . As it stands, your question is far too open to interpretation.

Comment: "this returns the size in bytes" - no, it returns the size in characters. For `std::string` (aka `std::basic_string<char>`, where the character type is a byte), that's the same thing. You just happen to want something different - the size after filtering out certain types of characters.

Comment: Normally 1 character is 1 byte, but not always the case(Unicode for example), Even if I didn't want to filter things out the .size() function wouldn't work if the user typed in a multi byte character.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you want the length of the string in characters or you just want to count the number of letters and spaces.

There is no specific function that lets you count just letters and spaces, however you can get the amount of letters and spaces (and ignore all other types of characters) quite simply:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>    
int main() {
  std::string mystring = "Hello 123 World";
  int l = std::count_if(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), [](char c){ return isspace(c) || isalpha(c); });
  return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, unless you use non-ascii strings, `std::string::length` should work for you.

In general, it's not so simple and you're quite right if you assumed that one byte doesn't necessarily mean one character. However, if you're just learning, you don't have to deal with unicode and the accompanying nastiness yet. For now you can assume 1 byte is 1 character, just know that it's not generally true.

Comment: great answer! plus one

Comment: Thanks, I didn't assume 1 char was 1 byte, I will be using the above code because mystring can contain any character in my program, even unicode, and this solves another issue because I needed a way to filter out all other characters!

Answer (score 1):

Your first aim should be to figure out if the string is `ascii` encoded or encoded with a `multi-byte` format.

For ascii `string::size` would suffice. You could use the `length` property of string as well.

In the latter case you need to find the `number of bytes per character`.

Answer (score 1):

You should take the size of your array, in bytes, using `string::size` and then divide this by the size in bytes of an element of that string (a `char`).

That would look like: `int len = mystring.size() / sizeof(char);`

Just make sure to include `iostream`, the header file that contains std::sizeof.

Comment: But `sizeof(char)` is always and by definition 1

Comment: As al-Acme stated, `chars` may be encoded as multiple bytes. It would certainly be a rare situation though.

Comment: Indeed, some UTF8 characters (actually glyphs) are encoded in *several consecutive* `char`-s. But then you should use some UTF8 library computing the numbers of glyphs in an UTF8 string.

Answer (score -1):

You can make your own function to get the length of string in C++ (For std::string)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
int get_len(string str){
   int len = 0;
   char *ptr;
   while(*ptr != '\0')
  {
     ptr = &str[len];
     len++;
   }
   int f_len = len - 1;
   return f_len;
}
```

To use this function, simply use:

```
get_len("str");
```

Comment: This is basically just a very bad implementation of the strlen function from the C standard library.

Comment: ptr is used before set.

Comment: @Richard - Why is it?

Comment: @Richard, If it has some error, please tell me.. I'd love to learn more..

Comment: @MayukhChakraborty, You're passing `string` as a value leading to an unnecessary copy. `ptr` is uninitialized when you first use it (in the while condition) which leads to undefined behavior. `ptr = &str[len]; len++;` does not really make sense idiomatically. You can replace it by `++ptr; ++len;` or only `++ptr` and calculate len from `ptr - str` eventually.

Comment: The biggest problem with this answer though is that it suggests reimplementing a standard library function when just using that function would be perfectly acceptable. Don't reinvent the wheel!